# Delay jquery-plugin-circliful until div is in viewpoint

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to delay the jquery-plugin-circliful from starting the animation / loading until a div is in view, we load it at the bottom of the page on a scroller so the animation is missed by the time you get to it. I would like it to load when the div .stats comes into view ?

Current html:

```
<div class="stats">
                               <div id="myStat" class="inlined" data-dimension="250" data-text="57.4%" data-info="INCREASE IN WEEKLY REVENUE" data-width="10" data-fontsize="38" data-percent="57.4" data-fgcolor="#eee" data-bgcolor="transparent" data-fill="transparent"></div>
                               <div id="myStat2" class="inlined" data-dimension="250" data-text="68%" data-info="DECREASE IN CPA (MOM)" data-width="10" data-fontsize="38" data-percent="68" data-fgcolor="#eee" data-bgcolor="transparent" data-fill="transparent"></div>
                               <div id="myStat3" class="inlined" data-dimension="250" data-text="551%" data-info="INCREASE IN ROI (MOM)" data-width="10" data-fontsize="38" data-percent="551" data-fgcolor="#eee" data-bgcolor="transparent" data-fill="transparent"></div>
                            </div>
```

Current call:

```
<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#myStat').circliful();
            $('#myStat2').circliful();
            $('#myStat3').circliful();
            $('#myStat4').circliful();
            $('#myStat5').circliful();
            $('#myStat6').circliful();
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a standard option with circliful now.  Not sure if this is still an issue for you.